# Creating isometric dot background in css

Tags: html, css, background

Desired outcome:

[image: Text]

I want to create a background made with isometric dots. I've tried combining linear gradients to no avail. I don't want to use an image as that means I can't have dynamic foreground/background colors.

Comment: I think you want to use background-image and add background-repeat like in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679404/17803626)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `radial-gradient()` here:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  
  --s: 30px; /* control the space between circles */
             /*        v-- the radius of circle */
  --g: radial-gradient(5px at 25% 50%,red 96%,#0000);
  background: var(--g),var(--g) var(--s) calc(var(--s)/2);
  background-size: calc(2*var(--s)) var(--s);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this untill now, I just used a repeating background image in the end. But thanks anyway